# VB script Kill process and delete folder

Tags: vbscript

I am a noop when it comes to vbscript but I managed to make something. But now I am kinda stuck.

Let me try to explain what I am trying to do

I need to kill a process on a computer [That part I know and made] VBpart 1
When the process is killed I need to delete a folder with all it content [ That I managed also] VB part 2

**VB part 1**

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim xComputer, xProcessKill
xComputer = "."
xProcessKill = "'diamant client.exe'"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& xComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & xProcessKill)
For Each objProcess in colProcess
objProcess.Terminate()
next
```

**VB part 2**

```
strFolder = "\\srvad01\DFS\Sandbox$\username\sandbox\DiaSoft Framework Diamant Client 1.0 NL"

set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.DeleteFolder strFolder
```

But somehow I can't merge these 2 in 1 file While they work separate fine

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regarts Arie

Comment: Whats the problem? What error occured? What error message did you see?

Comment: You're killing a process on the local computer, but delete a folder on a remote computer. How do you want the 2 scripts merged? Should both operate on the same (remote) host?